# How do I position widgets next to each other in Glade?

Tags: development, glade, widgets

How can I make 2 widgets (or more) stand next to each other in Glade.

For example a textbar and a toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

you can do that with a *Box* or with a *Grid*. Both are aviable from the Containers-Section of the Palette.